# How to correctly name all those Launch Images for an universal app?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Default.png for iphone, Default4.png for iPhone 4 (or is it Default@2x.png?), and Default-iPad.png. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default.png and Default@2x.png and Default-iPad.png (not 100% sure on this one)

if you specify your own name like MyLaunchImage.png, the iPad specific version would be MyLaunchImage~ipad.png. Although you could include a MyLaunchImage~iphone.png image for the iPhone specific version (and a MyLaunchImage@2x~iphone.png for the high-resolution variant)

taken from apple documentation

Answer (score 59):

Here's the list of default launch image file names as of iOS 6:

- Default.png (iPhone)
- Default@2x.png (iPhone Retina 3.5 inch)
- Default-568h@2x.png (iPhone Retina 4 inch)
- Default-Portrait.png (iPad in portrait orientation)
- Default-Portrait@2x.png (iPad Retina in portrait orientation)
- Default-Landscape.png (iPad in landscape orientation)
- Default-Landscape@2x.png (iPad Retina in landscape orientation)

You can set the key `UILaunchImageFile` in your `info.plist` to override `Default` in all of the file names above.  For example, if you specify the value `LaunchImage` in this key, then the launch image for a standard resolution iPhone would be `LaunchImage.png`.

Additionally, if you want to provide separate launch images for iPad apps that are flipped 180-degrees from the standard, you can substitute the following modifiers in place of `-Portrait` and `-Landscape`:

- -Portrait (home button down)
- -PortraitUpsideDown (home button on top)
- -LandscapeLeft (home button on left side)
- -LandscapeRight (home button on right side)

Comment: iPad mini uses the same images as iPad2 (Default-Portrait.png and Default-Landscape.png from above reply)

Comment: Please also note the device specific modifiers like `~ipad` and `~iphone`. So a launch image for portrait retina iPad should actually be named as `Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png`.

Comment: Where are these file names listed officially?

Comment: iamjustaprogrammer: nowhere.

Comment: @Henrik Hah! Typical Apple.

Answer (score 30):

I adjusted Rob/Lando's answer with the latest iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus resolutions.

- Default.png (iPhone)
- Default@2x.png (iPhone Retina 3.5 inch)
- **Default@3x.png (iPhone 6 Plus landscape)**
- Default-568h@2x.png (iPhone Retina 4 inch)
- **Default-667h@2x.png (iPhone 6 portrait)**
- **Default-736h@3x.png (iPhone 6 Plus portrait)**
- Default-Portrait.png (iPad in portrait orientation)
- Default-Portrait@2x.png (iPad Retina in portrait orientation)
- **Default-Portrait@3x.png (iPhone 6 Plus portrait)**
- Default-Landscape.png (iPad in landscape orientation)
- Default-Landscape@2x.png (iPad Retina in landscape orientation)

Comment: It's incorrect: `Default-Portrait@3x.png (iPhone 6 Plus landscape)`.

Comment: How about those not including the status bar height?

Comment: Use Default-Portrait-1366h@2x.png and Default-Landscape-1366h@2x.png for iPad Pro

Answer (score 10):

I've just found a [handy table](http://www.iosres.com) with all the filenames for the Default launch image, I've posted it here to save some time in the future instead of looking for something similar or waste time browsing my endless list of bookmarks.

Comment: Yep, this work for me, except for iphone 6 which probably has to be specified in the info.plist. I dread the future, already it's tons of work. With the huge list of devices, Apple will probably have to do what they should have done from the beginning - ask for 1 hires image and spend .01% CPU time scaling and cropping it to the device used. "How hard can it be?", the developer cries. Apple answers, "As hard as possible."

Comment: @Henrik Hah! Typical Apple.

Answer (score 2):

I inspected the files in the main bundle (iOS 9 using LaunchImage in image assets) and this is what I see:

```
[
'LaunchImage-568h@2x.png',
'LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png',
'LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png',
'LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png',
'LaunchImage-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png',
'LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png',
'LaunchImage-700@2x.png',
'LaunchImage-800-667h@2x.png',
'LaunchImage-800-Landscape-736h@3x.png',
'LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h@3x.png',
'LaunchImage-Landscape@2x~ipad.png',
'LaunchImage-Landscape~ipad.png',
'LaunchImage-Portrait@2x~ipad.png',
'LaunchImage-Portrait~ipad.png',
'LaunchImage.png',
'LaunchImage@2x.png'
]
```