# iOS8 icons sizes and names for icons and launch image

Tags: ios, icons, ios8, launchimage

I am not finding a straight forward site with the iOS8 sizes and names for the app icons and launch image.

I have seen the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) but they don't really tell you how to name them.

Can someone list them out specifically?

Comment: You don't need any specific names. Use the asset catalog for the icons and launch images. Then you simply drag and drop the right sized images into their spot. Easy.

Comment: In the [iOS HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1) the documentation is confusing:  “If you’re using static launch images, you can give each image a name that specifies how it should be used. The format of the launch image filename includes modifiers you use to specify the device, resolution, and orientation of the image. To learn how to name launch images appropriately, see App Launch (Default) Images in *App Programming Guide for iOS*.  (Embedded links too long for comment)

Comment: check out this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/89816/porting-app-iphone-6-iphone-6-plus-ios-8-top-10-tips

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As rmaddy mentioned since Xcode 5 **you don't need to name your icons in any specific way**. Use the `App Icon Asset` to add your icons.

Regarding the sizes for your icons, you'll also find them in your App Icon Asset Catalog, but for convenience here's a screenshot:
[image][image]

I also highly recommend using this icon template to create your icon because one: it provide an awesome psd file ready to edit and second: it provides actions to easily save every icon you need!
Here it is: http://appicontemplate.com

Comment: And you can open the right panel in Xcode to see the expected size of each image.

Answer (score 38):

Autogenerate all necessary icon and launch image files (iOS 7 and above) with the following scripts:

http://github.com/spren9er/s9icongen

http://github.com/spren9er/s9splashgen

When the script is executed all sizes and names will be displayed in the console, e.g. for launch images

```
   320x480(2x) ->   640x960: Default@2x~iphone.png
   320x568(2x) ->  640x1136: Default-568h@2x~iphone.png
   375x667(2x) ->  750x1334: Default-667h@2x~iphone.png
   414x736(3x) -> 1242x2208: Default-736h@3x~iphone.png
  768x1024(1x) ->  768x1024: Default-Portrait~ipad.png
  1024x768(1x) ->  1024x768: Default-Landscape~ipad.png
  768x1024(2x) -> 1536x2048: Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
  1024x768(2x) -> 2048x1536: Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
```

Comment: And iPhone 6 Plus Landscape?

Comment: @Altaveron: Is there a landscape launch image for iPhone? I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, it is. For iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199231/is-it-okay-to-leave-out-unnecessary-launch-images Any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

This here is handy if you would like to know what the different files are good for:

- Default.png (iPhone)
- Default@2x.png (iPhone Retina 3.5 inch)
- Default@3x.png (iPhone 6 Plus landscape)
- Default-568h@2x.png (iPhone Retina 4 inch)
- Default-667h@2x.png (iPhone 6 portrait)
- Default-736h@3x.png (iPhone 6 Plus portrait)
- Default-Portrait.png (iPad in portrait orientation)
- Default-Portrait@2x.png (iPad Retina in portrait orientation)
- Default-Portrait@3x.png (iPhone 6 Plus portrait orientation)
- Default-Landscape.png (iPad in landscape orientation)
- Default-Landscape@2x.png (iPad Retina in landscape orientation)

Also check stackoverflow's thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27108377/4288147

Comment: It's incorrect: `Default-Portrait@3x.png (iPhone 6 Plus landscape)`.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199231/is-it-okay-to-leave-out-unnecessary-launch-images Any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any name for icons as there is no requirement for any specific name. To get icons with proper sizes you can use following shell script to generate them without any additional tools:

```
FILE="largeicon.png"
# iTunes Artwork
sips --resampleWidth 1024 "${FILE}" --out "iTunesArtwork@2x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 512 "${FILE}" --out "iTunesArtwork.png"
# iPhone iOS 7, 8
sips --resampleWidth 58 "${FILE}" --out "icon-iphone-29@2x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 87 "${FILE}" --out "icon-iphone-29@3x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 80 "${FILE}" --out "icon-iphone-40@2x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 120 "${FILE}" --out "icon-iphone-40@3x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 120 "${FILE}" --out "icon-iphone-60@2x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 180 "${FILE}" --out "icon-iphone-60@3x.png"
# iPad iOS 7, 8
sips --resampleWidth 29 "${FILE}" --out "icon-ipad-29.png"
sips --resampleWidth 58 "${FILE}" --out "icon-ipad-29@2x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 40 "${FILE}" --out "icon-ipad-40.png"
sips --resampleWidth 80 "${FILE}" --out "icon-ipad-40@2x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 76 "${FILE}" --out "icon-ipad-76.png"
sips --resampleWidth 152 "${FILE}" --out "icon-ipad-76@2x.png"
# Apple Watch
sips --resampleWidth 48 "${FILE}" --out "icon-watch-24@2x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 55 "${FILE}" --out "icon-watch-27p5@2x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 58 "${FILE}" --out "icon-watch-29@2x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 87 "${FILE}" --out "icon-watch-29@3x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 80 "${FILE}" --out "icon-watch-40@2x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 88 "${FILE}" --out "icon-watch-44@2x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 172 "${FILE}" --out "icon-watch-86@2x.png"
sips --resampleWidth 196 "${FILE}" --out "icon-watch-98@2x.png"
```