# iPad Splash Screen setting warning in App Target

Tags: ios, ipad, splash-screen

These are the splash screen of my iPad application.

- Default-Portrait.png (768 × 1024)
- Default-Portrait@2x.png (1536 × 2048)
- Default-Landscape.png (1024 × 768)
- Default-Landscape@2x.png (1024 × 768)

The problem:
I upload all these screen in my application. Then set
`Default-Landscape@2x`, `Default-Landscape` & `Default-Portrait`
 in App Target as iPad Splash screen.

Now when I try to set `Default-Portrait@2x`, I find **"No image Specified"** message in **"Portrait Non-Retina"** section.
Like this:

[image]

And then when try to set `Default-Portrait` again, I find **"No image with correct dimensions found"** message in **"Portrait Retina"** section. 
Like this:

[image]

And this thing happen no matter how many times I re change them one after one. What is the reason of it? If any one have any clue please share that with me. I check my "image name" and "size", no problem in there. I set these splash in a **Cross platform "Cordova"** project.
Thanks in advanced. Have a nice day.

**Addition:**

I also try it with these names, but no luck.

- Default-Portrait~iPad.png (768 × 1024)
- Default-Portrait~iPad@2x.png (1536 × 2048)
- Default-Landscape~iPad.png (1024 × 768)
- Default-Landscape~iPad@2x.png (1024 × 768)
- List item

Comment: Shouldn't you have some Default images with `-ipad` on them? You can't use your iPhone images for your iPad images. See the answers given on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973981/how-to-correctly-name-all-those-launch-images-for-an-universal-app and here's another userful link http://www.iosres.com/ that shows your naming is wrong

Comment: @Thanks Popeye for commenting. You mean add `~ipad` in every image image? Like `Default-Portrait~ipad.png` ???

Comment: My apologies, yeah add `~ipad` but remember you still need both iPad and iPhone images.

Comment: @Popeye It's Ok. I've tried with adding `~ipad` but, still the same thing. Yes, I've separate images for iPhone & iPad and the iPhone didn't do any problem here. I think I have the naming problem. But what's the problem is?? :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it didn't take the default name in this case. But I set it with the following name and solve it. If anyone get into the similar problem try with these name:

- Default~ipad.png
- Default~ipad@2x.png
- Default-Landscape~ipad.png
- Default-Landscape~ipad@2x.png