# iOS Simulator Launch Screens and Images BLACK

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator, launch

When I run my app in the simulator, I receive a black launch image, even though (I think) I have assigned the launch image in settings to the set in my asset catalog. I think the problem could be with whatever 'launch screen' is, but I might be wrong.

It would be great if someone could please explain what I am doing badly!

Thanks in advance,

Will

**Update**

I have fixed the problem - please see my answer if you also had this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are very specific 'naming' rules about launch images. If you have this problem, follow these guidelines. I was using portrait launch images, I am sure that it's similar if  you are using landscape images.

Call it whatever you want but make sure to include the correct suffix:

2x = **@2x**

Retina 4 = **-568h@2x**

Retina HD 4.7 = **@2x**

Retina HD 5.5 = **@3x**

Here are the sizes that you should use when creating your launch images (for your convenience):

2x = **640 x 960**

Retina 4 = **640 x 1136**

Retina HD 4.7 = **750 x 1334**

Retina HD 5.5 = **1242 x 2208**

Hope this helps,

Will

Comment: That's wrong you can't call the launch images whatever you want. The launch images have to be called `Default` so you would have something like `Default@2x.png` and `Default-568h@2x.png`.

Comment: @Popeye I have called my Launch Images 'LaunchImage' and put them into an Asset Catalog - my iOS Simulator seems to accept them.

Comment: Unless they have changed it in the latest xcode they should have the prefix `Default` probably best to read the Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH66-SW1 but here's a link that could be of interest to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973981/how-to-correctly-name-all-those-launch-images-for-an-universal-app