# Updated launch image naming convention for all devices

Tags: ios, uiimageview

All the resources I have gone through are quite old and don't provide the complete set of names for a launch image. Like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973981/how-to-correctly-name-all-those-launch-images-for-an-universal-app).
I am aware that launch image set take care of that, but while using it for a full screen UIImageView, it doesn't work. So I am going by the old way.
[**This**](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/) is Apple's link for the list of devices and their resolutions. Screenshot :

[image]

I have managed to get most of the names other than :

> iPad Pro 10.5 inch
>   iPad Pro 12.9 inch
>   iPad Pro 12.9 inch 2nd generation

Comment: A single launch screen storyboard is so much simpler than dealing with separate launch images.

Comment: @rmaddy : But like I said, it doesn't work. Named the imageSet as commonBackground and placed all the variations. Used the name commonBackground in UIImageView's image, but it didn't work.